# How to setup session timeout in Ruby on Rails and redirect to login page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, before-filter

I am new to ruby, using version 1.8.7. Please guide me in setting up session timeout and redirection to my login page.

**Config:**

```
ActionController::Base.session = { :key => '_fleetsmartlive_session', :secret => 'e9e5983619325de4f',expire_after => 5.minutes', }
```

Comment: Please add some sample code

Comment: ActionController::Base.session = {
  :key         => '_fleetsmartlive_session',
  :secret      => 'e9e5983619325de4f',
  expire_after => 5.minutes'

Comment: Please update your question with: what you've tried, what auth library you're using (devise?), how it isn't working as expected.

Comment: no iam not using devise

Comment: in config/initializers/session_store.rb

ActionController::Base.session = {
  :key         => 'session',`enter code here`
  :secret      => 'abd027d54d0cd9c410a8723',
  :expire_after => 5.minutes 
  }

Comment: You left out many important details, such as how your app determines if someone is logged in or not, how it handles non-logged-in users that try to get to a page that requires being logged in, and what is stored in the session.

Answer (score 3):

*Add this at the top of application controller*

```
before_filter :session_expiry
before_filter :update_activity_time
```

*Add these methods in application controller. 
This makes the session timeout,if the page remain idle for some amount of time.*

```
def session_expiry

   get_session_time_left
   unless @session_time_left > 0
     flash.now[:error] = "Your session has timed out. Please log back in."
     sign_out
   end
end

def get_session_time_left 

   expire_time = session[:expires_at] || Time.now  
   @session_time_left = (expire_time - Time.now).to_i  
end

def update_activity_time
  session[:expires_at] = 3.minutes.from_now
end
```

Comment: What is the time set for the session here please

Comment: The above code is not allowing me to login. Its redirecting to home when i click on the sign in

Comment: updated the answer please check.

Comment: with above code after 3min it should show me  error message and redirect me to login page. but it is not working

Answer (score 1):

Should be simple, add this in your application controller

```
before_filter :check_session_expiry, if: proc{!resquest.url.include?('/signin')}

def check_session_expiry
  if !session[:expires_at].nil? and session[:expires_at] < Time.now
    redirect_to signin_url
  end
  session[:expires_at] = MAX_SESSION_TIME.seconds.from_now
end
```

Comment: i tried this solution already.no luck